# asp.net textboxes out of place

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having an issue with either Visual Studio or ASP.NET. I've laid out controls in an html table but the TextBox and DropDownList controls appear out of place in the table and just hog the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Here's the markup, as you can see the textboxes "should" all be within the  elements:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th colspan="6">
               <asp:Label ID="Search_Header" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" meta:resourcekey="Search_HeaderResource1" Font-Size="16pt"></asp:Label>
           </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="controls">
       <tr>
           <td style="height: 22px">
                  <asp:Label ID="Destination" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="DestinationResource1" ></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td style="height: 22px">
               <asp:TextBox ID="Destination_Text" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="TextBox1Resource1"></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
           <td style="height: 22px">
               <asp:Label ID="Check_In" runat="server" Text="Label" meta:resourcekey="Check_InResource1"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td style="height: 22px">
<asp:TextBox ID="Check_In_Date" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Check_In_DateResource1" TextMode="DateTime" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="Check_In_Date_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="Check_In_Date" BehaviorID="Check_In_Date_CalendarExtender" />
           </td>
           <td style="height: 22px">
                 <asp:Label ID="Check_Out" runat="server" Text="Label" meta:resourcekey="Check_OutResource1"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td style="height: 22px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Check_Out_Date" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Check_Out_DateResource1" TextMode="DateTime" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="Check_Out_Date_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="Check_Out_Date" BehaviorID="Check_Out_Date_CalendarExtender" />
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr style="margin-bottom: 5px">
           <td></td>
           <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Destination_Validator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Resource, Required_Field %>" ControlToValidate="Destination_Text" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td></td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Check_In_Validator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Resource, Required_Field %>" ControlToValidate="Check_In_Date" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
           <td></td>
           <td>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Check_Out_Validator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Resource, Required_Field %>" ControlToValidate="Check_Out_Date" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <asp:Label ID="Adults" runat="server" Text="Label" meta:resourcekey="AdultsResource1"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="Adult_Count" runat="server" type="number" TextMode="Number" meta:resourcekey="Adult_CountResource1" ForeColor="Black" MaxLength="2" Width="20px" Font-Size="10pt" ReadOnly="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="Adult_Count_NumericUpDownExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="Adult_Count" Minimum="1" Width="50" BehaviorID="Adult_Count_NumericUpDownExtender" Maximum="10" RefValues="" ServiceDownMethod="" ServiceDownPath="" ServiceUpMethod="" Tag="" TargetButtonDownID="" TargetButtonUpID="" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
           </td>
           <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Children" runat="server" Text="Label" meta:resourcekey="ChildrenResource1"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="Child_Count" runat="server" type="number" TextMode="Number" meta:resourcekey="Child_CountResource1" ForeColor="Black" MaxLength="2" Width="20px" Font-Size="10pt" ReadOnly="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="Child_Count_NumericUpDownExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="Child_Count" Minimum="0" Width="50" BehaviorID="Child_Count_NumericUpDownExtender" Maximum="10" RefValues="" ServiceDownMethod="" ServiceDownPath="" ServiceUpMethod="" Tag="Child" TargetButtonDownID="" TargetButtonUpID="" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:Label ID="Room_Size" runat="server" Text="Label" meta:resourcekey="Room_SizeResource1"></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="Room_Size_List" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Room_Size_ListResource1">
                <asp:ListItem meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1">1 adult</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2">2 adults</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this all of the css for the page?

Comment: the only relevant css is the "controls" class, where I set the table to relative position and its children to absolute. Still not working

Comment: the problem persists even after restarting my computer. oh, and the "Search" button in the image is also supposed to be below the table (and it isn't)

Comment: Temporarily remove row two with the required field validators. Do the texboxes line up now? You may not have given enough space for them. Subsequently, you may also need to add the height = 22 on the third row as well. Try those two things.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised what the problem is. I was careless; I unknowingly tampered with the Site.css file (the master stylesheet) such that this style

```
input,
select,
textarea {
max-width: 280px;
position: absolute;
top: 240px;
left: 193px;
z-index: 1;
right: 496px;
 }
```

caused the problems.
By removing top, left, z-index and right, the controls were back in place.